# What's going wrong in this basic snippet

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, memory

I was working on a personal project when I found that something was going wrong in my code. After few minutes of debugging, I was able to tell what was wrong and how to workaround. But in fact I don't have resolved my original issue.

Look at this:

```
interface Animals {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    color: string;
}

interface Zoo {
    name: string;
    animals: Animals[];
}

function main() {
    let zoo: Zoo = {
        name : "Valley of monkeys",
        animals : [
            {
                id : 1,
                name: "Foufou",
                color: "brown"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Toutou",
                color: "brown"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Moumou",
                color: "blue"
            }
        ]
    };

    let zoobis: Zoo;

    zoobis = zoo;

    console.log(zoobis);
    console.log(zoo);

    zoobis.animals = zoo.animals.filter((animal) => animal.color === "brown");

    console.log("============");
    console.log(zoobis);
    console.log(zoo);
}

main();
```

[**Link to Typescript Playground to test it**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Animals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%09id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%09color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Zoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09animals%3A%20Animals%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20zoo%3A%20Zoo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%3A%20%22Valley%20of%20monkeys%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20animals%20%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%20%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Foufouf%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%22brown%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Toutou%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%22brown%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Moumou%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%22blue%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20let%20zoobis%3A%20Zoo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20zoobis%20%3D%20zoo%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(zoobis)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log(zoo)%3B%0D%0A%20%20zoobis.animals%20%3D%20zoo.animals.filter((animal)%20%3D%3E%20animal.color%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22brown%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log(%22%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(zoobis)%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(zoo)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Amain()%3B) :

As you can see there are two mains problems :

- The first one is that both arrays are modified! Even though in the javascript official documentation, it specified that "filter() does not mutate the array on which it is called."
- The second one is that both arrays are modified before the call of filter which is weird actually.

The workaround is basically to convert "zoobis" into an Animal[] instead of taking the whole Zoo object. It seems to normally work in this way.

Am I misunderstanding a basic concept of javascript or am I doing stupid mistakes that makes my code doing weird things?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
zoobis = zoo;
```

just makes both the `zoobis` and the `zoo` variables point at the **same** object. Then, the line

```
zoobis.animals = zoo.animals.filter((animal) => animal.color === "brown");
```

modifies the state of the **one** object both variables are pointing at, replacing its `animals` property with a new filtered array.

Naturally, you see the same object state regardless of whether you look at it via `zoobis` or via `zoo`, as both of those variables refer to the same object.

Some ASCII-art:

Once you've created the `zoo` object, you have something vaguely like this in memory:

```
                                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                                                                       +−>|    (object)    |                    
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
zoo:[Ref71234]−−−−−−>|         (object)          |                     |  | id: 1          |                    
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  | name: "Foufou" |                    
                     | name: "Valley of monkeys" |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | color: "brown" |                    
                     | animals: [Ref55412]       |−−>|    (array)    | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                                        
                                                     | 0: [Ref45132] |−+                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                     | 1: [Ref45174] |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|    (object)    |
                                                     | 2: [Ref45228] |−+                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | id: 2          |
                                                                       +−>|    (object)    |  | name: "Toutou" |
                                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | color: "brown" |
                                                                          | id: 3          |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                          | name: "Moumou" |                    
                                                                          | color: "blue"  |                    
                                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice that `zoo` contains a reference to the object (conceptually shown above as [Ref71234], but you never actually see the value of an object reference in code).

Then after `zoobis = zoo;` you have:

```
zoo:[Ref71234]−−+
                |                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                |                                                      +−>|    (object)    |                    
                |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                +−−−>|         (object)          |                     |  | id: 1          |                    
                |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  | name: "Foufou" |                    
                |    | name: "Valley of monkeys" |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | color: "brown" |                    
                |    | animals: [Ref55412]       |−−>|    (array)    | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
zoo:[Ref71234]−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                                        
                                                     | 0: [Ref45132] |−+                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                     | 1: [Ref45174] |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|    (object)    |
                                                     | 2: [Ref45228] |−+                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | id: 2          |
                                                                       +−>|    (object)    |  | name: "Toutou" |
                                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | color: "brown" |
                                                                          | id: 3          |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                          | name: "Moumou" |                    
                                                                          | color: "blue"  |                    
                                                                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice how the value of `zoo` ([Ref71234]) was copied into `zoobis`, but that value is just a reference to the **one** object.

Then after [filter]:

```
zoo:[Ref71234]−−+
                |                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                |                                                      +−>|    (object)    |                    
                |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                +−−−>|         (object)          |                     |  | id: 1          |                    
                |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                     |  | name: "Foufou" |                    
                |    | name: "Valley of monkeys" |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | color: "brown" |                    
                |    | animals: [Ref65241]       |−−>|    (array)    | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
zoo:[Ref71234]−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |                                        
                                                     | 0: [Ref45132] |−+                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                     | 1: [Ref45174] |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|    (object)    |
                                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                                              | id: 2          |
                                                                                              | name: "Toutou" |
                                                                                              | color: "brown" |
                                                                                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice how you replaced the old `animals` value ([Ref55412]) with a new value ([Ref65241]) because you created and stored a new array.

If you want to **copy** `zoo`, you can use `Object.assign` or property spread (ES2018+):

```
zoobis = Object.assign({}, zoo);
// or
zoobis = {...zoo};
```

That makes a **shallow** copy (so for instance, both objects' `animals` property points to the **same** array). A shallow copy is sufficient for what you've shown (but might be problematic if you have other properties on `zoo` referring to objects).

If you want to make a *deep* copy, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/157247).

Comment: But i'm not asking for a reference in this case. How can i create a duplicate of "zoo" and assign it to "zoobis" ?

Comment: You can copy the zoo object as zoobis by using zoobis = {...zoo}; (spread into new object)

Comment: @Ragaan - *"But i'm not asking for a reference in this case."* That's what `zoobis = zoo;` does, it copies the value of `zoo` (an object reference) into `zoobis`. I've updated the answer to show more detail and to talk about object copying at the end.

Comment: Big big thanks guys, i was not aware of this default behavior of javascript. In my experience you have to specify explicitely if you want to have a reference instead of a copy (like the "&" in C). Thank you for taking the time to answer me :)

Comment: @Ragaan - No worries! FWIW, this is fairly common outside the C family of languages, even in languages that are in the same syntactic tradition. Java, JavaScript, Go, C#, PHP, Python -- they all work this way. C++'s object variables that trigger a copy constructor on assignment (IIRC) are a bit unusual (but in their way, cool). Object references in the languages I mentioned basically work like C pointers. Happy coding!

Comment: That ASCII-art is fantastic. Did you use any site to create that or copied one *box* from somewhere and created rest on your own?

Comment: @adiga - Thanks! Just used `vim` (the text editor). :-)